# use regexp to search function calls in code

Tags: php, regex, po, mo

i try to make .mo files from my sources in php by finding "t()" function calls, i know that one better way is using regex functions like preg_match or something, but i'm not the better creating regular expresions, any help?

(and sorry for my english...)

Comment: Please provide some examples of the input and clearly indicate what substrings you're trying to match.

Comment: @Bart: I believe the author wants to generate .mo files as generated by gettext. The `t()` function is probably equivalent of gettext's `_()` function. The author needs to find all these function calls in order to get the untranslated source strings.

Comment: @Sander, it's exactly what you say, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `preg_match` is not better. When you want to parse PHP code, use the [`tokenizer`](http://nl2.php.net/tokenizer). It is far more reliable.

Comment: ohhh thank you very much, i googled for this solution a lot, maybe i dont know how to google in the correct terms :( , i do some tests and its just that i need, thank you very much again!!!

Comment: @DavidB: If this solves your problem please consider [accepting my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the big "tick" icon on my answer. Thank you.

Comment: of course, sorry, this was my first question here and i didnt know, done.

Comment: Could you go into more detail? The tokenizer returns the same token constant for function calls as it does for plain old strings (it gives back T_STRING) so it's not clear how to be sure that you've found a call to the function t versus a string that contains the letter t. (I'm on 5.3.11, but the docs don't mention any constant for function calls, so I assume this is the same across all versions.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no function calls within the t() call, the simplest way to match them is

```
t\([^)]*?\)
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't explain so good, there is a lot of code around de t() calls, but thankyou for your time & help